# Java Bean not getting loaded

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a xpage which uses a java bean to generate some content on the page. The page gives error "Error 500 HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception". But error just disappears once I open the database using designer. I do not do any modifications to the database, but just open the database using designer client. I have to open the database every day to fix this problem. Can anybody tell me why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use XPages Log File Reader from OpenNTF to see the details of the error/stack trace in the XPages log. Then post the error description in your question.

Comment: Thanks Per Hnrik, I checked the xpages log under IBM Technical support folder and found that it is flagging following error with trace log "Exception Thrown
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:The import com.ibm.xsp.extlib cannot be resolved ExtLibUtil cannot be resolved" with other trace log. I tried to resign the updatesite.nsf, but still have the same problem.

Comment: Check that the server has loaded extlib by using "tell http osgi ss" on the server console

Comment: Checked the server console and it does show that various extlib modules are active. But I cannot find any extlibutil.

Answer (score 3):

"Error 500" is a pretty catch-all error description, and I believe it shows up if you don't tell the app to display the XPages runtime error page (the default with the stack trace) or provide your own. If you do one of those (or look at the server console and error-log-0.xml in the data/domino/workspace/logs folder), you may be able to get a more-specific description of the problem.

But one plausible "crops up every day" type of problem I've run into is the "X is incompatible with X" ClassCastException problem - at some point in the growth of most XPages apps, this starts to crop up (I don't know why other than "using Java") and gets to the point where even changing non-XPage design and potentially data docs triggers it. Fortunately, the fix is easy: assuming you're running 8.5.3 or above, go into the xsp.properties and check the option to "Refresh entire application on design change" (or thereabouts). That should fix it if this is indeed your problem.

Comment: Thanks Jasse for quick response. Log file just says "CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown" "CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /<filename-xpage> - HTTP Code: 500" As for the .xsp properties, I am running 8.5.3 FP6 and I do not see the option. Can you please give me the exact code to add there?

Comment: The code that the checkbox sets in the file is: xsp.application.forcefullrefresh=true

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was my designer client. I was using 8.5.3 without any fix packs. I installed FP6 and signed the design again and the problem is fixed.